# Tkinter window geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on Tkinter window, and I want to set up the height and width of the screen without the geometry function, so I made 2 scales vertical and horizontal, then I use a button with a command that set up the window size in the following code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Root window")

label = Label(root, text="The height").pack()
slay = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200)

slay.pack()

my_label = Label(root, text="The width").pack()

hor = Scale(root, from_=0, to=250, orient=HORIZONTAL)

hor.pack()

def btns():
 root.geometry(str(f"{slay.get} x {hor.get}"))

btn = Button(root, text="Setup the window size", command=btns).pack()
```

And the error is:
line 20, in btns
root.geometry(str(f"{slay.get} x {hor.get}"))

Comment: Use two steps for `btns`. First, compute the string and save it in a variable, and then pass it to `geometry`. When you do that you'll be able to see what you're passing to `geometry`. It won't be what you are assuming it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are just referencing the `.get()` function, never actually calling them. So you will receive an error.

Call the function using `()`. Also, there is no space between `str(f"{slay.get()} x {hor.get()}")`.

So it would look something like this:

```
root.geometry(str(f"{slay.get()}x{hor.get()}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried several times with () but it doesn't work, try it

Comment: again thank you, but I figure out how to do it is like that:     
  root.geometry((str(hor.get()) + "x" + str(slay.get())))

Answer (score 0):

This works.

The problem was `root.geometry(str(f"{vert.get} x {hori.get}"))`

I changed it to this `root.geometry(str(f"{vert.get()}x{hori.get()}"))`

Simply removed the spaces around 'x' and added `()` to the `get`

Also added orient = `VERTICAL` to slay

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("Root window")

label = Label(root, text="The height").pack()
slay = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200, orient=VERTICAL)

slay.pack()

my_label = Label(root, text="The width").pack()

hor = Scale(root, from_=0, to=250, orient=HORIZONTAL)

hor.pack()

def btns():
    print( slay.get(), hor.get() )
    root.geometry(str(f"{slay.get()}x{hor.get()}"))

btn = Button(root, text="Setup the window size", command=btns).pack()

root.mainloop()
```